# Why is this ruby method not being defined in my class?

Tags: ruby

Here's the code:

```
module Dog
  class Breed < Animal::Base

    class << self
      def all
        get '/v1/breeds'
      end

      def find(hashed_id)
        get "/v1/breeds/#{breed_id}"
      end
    end

    def bark
      "woof"
    end
  end
end
```

And for the base:

```
module Dog
  class Base < ActiveRecord::Base
    include HTTParty

    base_uri 'https://api.dogs.com'
    format :json
    default_params api_password: ENV['ANIMAL_PASSWORD']
  end
end

module HTTParty
  module ClassMethods
    def get(path, options = {}, &block)
      response = perform_request(Net::HTTP::Get, path, options, &block)
      if response.is_a? Array
        methodize_array response
      elsif response.is_a? Hash
        new_ros response
      end
    end

    def methodize_array(response)
      array = []

      response.each do |res|
        array << new_ros(res)
      end

      array
    end

    private

    def new_ros(object)
      RecursiveOpenStruct.new(object, recurse_over_arrays: true)
    end
  end
end
```

This is a silly example, but it should work in theory. What happens is is that we grab some data from an API. When that data is grabbed, we discover that its a Hash. We don't like Hashes, so we reopen the get request within HTTParty and have it perform a [recursive open struct](https://github.com/aetherknight/recursive-open-struct) to make it an object.

We perform this get as `Dog::Breed.all`. We receive an array that, thankfully to ROS, was converted to an object.

Now, when I call `Dog::Breed.all.bark` it doesn't work:

```
undefined method `bark' for #<Array:0x007fc7acbb6108>
```

If I make it:

```
def self.bark
  "woof"
end
```

And then call `Dog::Breed.bark`, it will woof at me. How do I make it so that I can add methods to the `Breed` class so that I can do `Dog::Breed.all.bark` or `Dog::Breed.find(2).bark`?

The output from `Dog::Breed.all` was a `#<RecursiveOpenStruct>`. Disclaimer: That was an example case, not real life, `dog.com` leads to petsmart.

Comment: Just read the exception message carefully. `Dog::Breed.all` returns an Array as result of `get` method. Invoking *instance* method `bark` from that makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

`Dog::Breed.all` returns an `Array` of `Breed`, not `Breed`. If you want all dogs to bark you need to iterate over the array, and make each one bark:

```
Dog::Breed.all.each(&:bark)
```